# ArcGIS map service and image service in Cesium

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, map-service, cesium, image-service

Im trying to load an ArcGIS map service in Cesium with WMS protocol but I get this exception:

```
Error: error occurred in "v": Failed to obtain image tile X : 0 Y : 0 Level : 0.
```

When I publish the map service without WMS protocol it works fine (using `ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider`). I get the same exception when trying to show an image service.

I tried use both `WebMapServiceImageryProvider`, that is suppose to support WMS protocol, and `ArcGisMapServerImageryProvider` but that did not work as well.

For the map service I use this url: *http://server/arcgis/services/MapName/MapServer/WMSServer*. For the image service I use this url: *http://server/arcgis/services/MapName/ImageServer/WMSServer*

Could anyone help me show both map service published in WMS protocol and image service?

Comment: ArcGIS Server can publish using many different protocols, but you need to use the appropriate REST endpoint for each.  Please **edit** your question to contain the URLs you are attempting to use.

Comment: I added the URLs to my question.